# Clarification of proof in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

I was reading this corollary of theorem 4.8 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I need clarification as to why $f^{-1}(E^{c})=[f^{-1}(E)]^{c}$ for every $E \subset Y$.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Apply the definition of $f^{-1}(E) := \{ x \in X: f(x) \in E\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(E^c)
\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\in E^c &\Longleftrightarrow f(x)\notin E\\
&\Longleftrightarrow x\notin f^{-1}(E) \Longleftrightarrow x\in [f^{-1}(E)]^c
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the definitions of the two sets. For example, if $x \in f^{-1}(E^c)$, this means that $f(x) \in E^c$. This means that $f(x) \not \in E$ so that $x \not \in f^{-1}(E)$. Since $x \not \in f^{-1}(E)$, we must have that $x \in [f^{-1}(E)]^c$.

You can argue similarly for the opposite direction.